# Правильно ли расставлены кавычки и точки в конце текста?

Tags: пунктуация

Пункт 1.3. изложить в новой редакции:
«1.3. Работнику устанавливается учебная нагрузка:
«преподаватель» - 21,0 час в неделю;
«концертмейстер» - 1,0 час в неделю.».

Answer (score 1):

Кавычки лучше разные поставить: если весь текст в ёлочках, то должности можно заключить, например, в клавиатурные кавычки.

Точка ставится только одна: после закрывающих кавычек. После указания пункта точка не нужна при указании на него внутри фразы, правильно она стоит в начале закавыченной фразы (формат *номер пункта — его содержание*).

> Пункт 1.3 изложить в новой редакции:
> «1.3. Работнику устанавливается учебная нагрузка:
> преподаватель — 21,0 час в неделю;
> концертмейстер — 1,0 час в неделю».

Нули после запятой тоже убрал бы, но если этого требует форма, тогда ладно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Не за что! Если нравится ответ и не ждёте других особенно, можете принять его. ;)

Comment: Я одного не могу понять. Зачем закавычивать должности?

Comment: Точно, спасибо! Повторил авторские кавычки и даже не задумался. Сейчас поправлю.